# If $|\operatorname{Aut}_KF|=3$, must we have cube roots of unity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let $K$ be a field of zero characteristic. Let $F$ be a finite dimensional extension field of $K$ such that $|\operatorname{Aut}_K F|=3$. Must the equation $x^2+x+1=0$ have a root in $F$ ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you assume in addition that $F$ is Galois, then $F$ has degree $3$ and so can't contain a quadratic subextension. Hence for example if $K = \mathbb{Q}$, so that $K$ does not contain a third root of unity, this is impossible already for degree reasons. An explicit example is $F = \mathbb{Q}(\cos \frac{2\pi}{7})$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is not clear to me why $|Aut_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{Q}(\cos(\frac{2\pi}{7}))|=3$ ?

Comment: Oh, I already knew why. It is related to $x^6+x^5+...+1=x^3(x^3+x^{-3}+x^2+x^{-2}+x+x^{-1}+1)$. Thanks

Comment: No I am confused again. OK what I am able to do so far is that the minimal polynomial of $\cos(\frac{2\pi}{7})$ has degree 3. But I still don't know why $Aut_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{Q}(\cos(\frac{2\pi}{7}))$ is a group of order $3$

Comment: @Amr: let $\zeta_7 = e^{ \frac{2 \pi i}{7} }$ be a primitive seventh root of unity so that $2 \cos \frac{2 \pi}{7} = \zeta_7 + \zeta_7^{-1}$. The automorphism group is generated by the map $\zeta_7 \mapsto \zeta_7^3$ because $3$ is a primitive root $\bmod 7$. This is a corollary of the fundamental theorem of Galois theory together with the observation that $\mathbb{Q}(\cos \frac{2\pi}{7})$ is the fixed field of complex conjugation in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$.